# The SUM is not calculating correctly when I use multiple JOIN statements. Other items are calculating correct

Tags: mysql

When I run a simple SQL statement:

```
SELECT SUM(perfect) FROM damagelog WHERE driverid = 3
```

i get an output of 2, which is correct

When I do a more complicated SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
    dr.id, 
    dr.drivername, 
    ra.driverid, 
    AVG(ra.rating), 
    SUM(dam.perfect)    
FROM 
    drivers AS dr 
    JOIN driverratings AS ra ON ra.driverid = dr.id 
    JOIN damagelog as dam ON dam.driverid = dr.id 
WHERE dr.id =3
```

I get a value of 12. What am I doing wrong with my code ?

Comment: That's quite a broad question. Do you really want us to itemise everything wrong with this query, or would you rather we focus on helping you build a working query?

Comment: I'm looking for help building a working query.  I'm rather new at this, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: You already provided a query, which is fine. Would you edit your question to add sample data from the 3 tables, as well as current output and expected output ?

Comment: To understand why you get a 12? I suggest to run the SQL without the `AVG` and the `SUM`. My guess is that there are 6 `driverratings` for that `drivers.id`. Yeah, SUM can be a PITA sometimes when you join tables... zzzzzZZZz

Comment: @Strawberry, for an otherwise seasoned contributor, your condescending comments for an obvious new person to the site to me represents poor character :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to S/O.  You question is common, but since you are new, you dont know why, nor the term.  What you are running into is a Cartesian result (or product).  Basically this means that when joining to multiple tables, your original record can match multiple in other tables and thus bloat your answer.

You have drivers A, B and C.  Now, per example, driver "A" has 3 damage logs, your count is 3.  But now, you are also querying against driver ratings.  Driver "A" has 20 people.  So your query now applies driver A to every driver log to every rating.  So now 1 * 3 * 20 = 60 count.

To fix this, you would need to do pre-aggregates as your secondary and third table so you only get one answer per a single driver to prevent the duplications.  Here is what I THINK you are looking for.

```
SELECT 
      dr.id, 
      dr.drivername, 
      ra.driverAvgRating, 
      dam.PerfectCnt    
   FROM
      drivers dr
         LEFT JOIN
         ( Select
                 driverid,
                 avg( rating ) driverAvgRating
              from 
                 driverratings 
              group by
                 driverid ) ra 
            ON dr.id = ra.driverid
         LEFT JOIN
         ( select
                 driverid,
                 sum( perfect ) as PerfectCnt
              from
                 damagelog 
              group by
                 driverid ) dam 
            ON dr.id = dam.driverid
```

Now, the above where will return all drivers and their respective ratings.  Notice the subqueries are the joins to the original driver table.  But here, I have LEFT-JOINS. meaning, in this query, I want ALL Drivers REGARDLESS of a rating or a damage log.  You may have drivers that may have one, but not the other.  Dont you still want to see the driver if it was missing something in the other table?  If you had the query as regular (INNER-implied) JOIN, then this means a record MUST exist in both result sets to be returned.

In the field list, I have the alias from the subquery, but also the column name within that subquery representing the individual rating or count.  Now, this list may show NULL values on either side based on the LEFT-JOIN described.

To prevent NULLs, there is a coalesce() function and would be written like

```
SELECT 
      dr.id, 
      dr.drivername, 
      coalesce( ra.driverAvgRating, 0 ) FinalAvgRating, 
      coalesce( dam.PerfectCnt, 0 ) FinalPerfectCnt
   FROM
```

Where coalesce() states give me whatever the first value is, but if its NULL, give me the second instead.  So this way, your results can have an expected proper data type upon return and you don't have to keep testing for nulls for final output where ever needed.

Now I know your original query was for a specific driver, your query could be simplifed by having a column the result of a select query provided that query returns ONLY 1 VALUE, ONE ROW.

```
SELECT 
      dr.id, 
      dr.drivername, 
      ( Select avg( rating ) 
           from driverratings 
           where driverid = 3) FinalAvgRating, 
      ( select sum( perfect ) 
           from damagelog 
           where driverid = 3) FinalPerfectCnt
   FROM
      drivers dr
   where
      id = 3
```

Notice the COLUMNS are just a select query getting JUST the average and ONLY for that driver.

Hope this provides good clarification on your issue and future tasks

Comment: This is super helpful.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

this is usually happened when not including all field list in group by clause , try this

```
SELECT 
    dr.id, 
    dr.drivername, 
    ra.driverid, 
    AVG(ra.rating), 
    SUM(dam.perfect)    
FROM 
    drivers AS dr 
    JOIN driverratings AS ra ON ra.driverid = dr.id 
    JOIN damagelog as dam ON dam.driverid = dr.id 
WHERE dr.id =3
GROUP BY 
    dr.id, 
    dr.drivername, 
    ra.driverid
```

i hope that works , the tricky thing that you use to aggregate functions so i could not predict the behavior , but you got the general idea